# Move nonstandard SVN repository to BitBucket

Tags: git, svn

I am migrating my SVN repository to Git (BitBucket) using this [tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/migrating-synchronize). But I have not used standard SVN layout so it seems to be little problematic.

My SVN repo is simple copy of Android project.

```
/svn/dirname/project/app
```

There is no `trunk`, `branches` and `tags` subfolders. You can say that `project` equals to the trunk.

```
git svn clone --trunk=/project --authors-file=authors.txt https://host/svn/dirname project
Initialised empty Git repository in /home/osboxes/GitMigration/project/.git/
Checked out HEAD:
https://host/svn/dirname/project r300
```

Next step shall have been clean up but it failed. Maybe because I do not have any branches:

```
java -jar ~/svn-migration-scripts.jar clean-git
Could not retrieve the config for the key: svn-remote.svn.branches
```

But then it failed and I do not know how to continue

```
java -jar ~/svn-migration-scripts.jar sync-rebase
fatal: ambiguous argument 'remotes/trunk': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
Error finding tracking ref for branch master
```

Comment: why downvote? I do not understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me fixed. What I did:

1. rearranged SVN repository to standard layout
2. `git svn clone --stdlayout --prefix='' --authors-file=authors.txt https://host/svn/dirname project`

I found an attlassian issue #2 from 2014 with a reequest to add Git 2.0 compatibility. It has 22 votes and it is not resolved yet. There was a hint to use the `prefix` parameter.